# Simple Injector. How to reuse a decorator class more than once in object's decorator chain using Scoped lifestyle

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, decorator, simple-injector

I want to reuse same class more than once in a chain of decorated objects like this.

`InstrumentedTargetDecorator -> ResilientTargetDecorator -> InstrumetedTargetDecorator -> Target`

Note that `InstrumentedTargetDecorator` is used twice here on purpose.

This is how `SimpleInjector` syntax looks to get the above wired up

```cs
container.Register<ITarget, Target>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ITarget), typeof(InstrumentationTargetDecorator), Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ITarget), typeof(ResilienceTargetDecorator), Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.RegisterDecorator(
    typeof(ITarget), typeof(InstrumentationTargetDecorator), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

If run as is with standard options this will throw producing following warnings

> -[Ambiguous Lifestyles] The registration for ITarget (Async Scoped) maps to the same implementation (InstrumentationTargetDecorator) as
> the registration for ITarget (Scoped) does, but the registration maps
> to a different lifestyle. This will cause each registration to resolve
> to a different instance.

> -[Ambiguous Lifestyles] The registration for ITarget (Scoped) maps to the same implementation (InstrumentationTargetDecorator) as the
> registration for ITarget (Async Scoped) does, but the registration
> maps to a different lifestyle. This will cause each registration to
> resolve to a different instance.

(2 warning messages reported because there are 2 decorator registrations of `InstrumentationTargetDecorator`)

Only way I could actually get it to work is by *not* running `.Verify()` (and setting `EnableAutoVerification` to `false`). Needless to say this is not a viable option in practice.

There doesn't seem to be any way to suppress this warning for a single decorator registration, because the regular suppress warning playbook doesn't work for decorators i.e. decorator registrations aren't actually retrievable at registration time e.g.

`Container.GetRegistration<ITarget>()` produces the original/non-decorated instance (I suspect that's because decorators aren't really resolved until the object graph is built)

If I try to force the graph building

```
Container.Verify(VerificationOption.VerifyOnly);

var registration = Container.GetRegistration<ITarget>()?.Registration;
registration?.SuppressDiagnosticWarning(DiagnosticType.AmbiguousLifestyles, "I'm right");

Container.Verify();
```

I can get my hands on the outermost most `InstrumentationTargetDecorator` which then allows me to suppress one of the warning messages, but not the other one.

---

Some more context and the actual program below

Originally I had this setup like this

`ResilientTargetDecorator -> Target`

(ResilientTargetDecorator wraps Target)

Then I decided to measure how long the Target method call takes, so I introduced a new decorator

`ResilientTargetDecorator -> InstrumetedTargetDecorator -> Target`

So far so good, this works as expected.

But what if I now want to re-use that instrumentation decorator to also measure how long the entire chain takes including the resilient target decorator ?

---

Program to reproduce this issue here

https://dotnetfiddle.net/zESxqc

Comment: This bug has been fixed in Simple Injector v5.3.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encountered a bug in Simple Injector. <strike>I will try to fix this in the next patch release.</strike> This bug has been fixed in v5.3.3.

As workaround, when working in an older release, create a derivative of the decorator inside your Composition Root and make that derivative the second registration. Hopefully this suppresses the invalid warning:

```cs
class Derivative: InstrumentationTargetDecorator { ...}


container.Register<ITarget, Target>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
 container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ITarget), typeof(InstrumentationTargetDecorator), Lifestyle.Scoped);
 container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ITarget), typeof(ResilienceTargetDecorator), Lifestyle.Scoped);
 container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ITarget), typeof(Derivative), Lifestyle.Scoped);
```

Comment: You can follow the progress of this issue here: https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/925